# Is it possible to invoke a GET request during a Browserstack session?

Tags: python, selenium, browserstack

During a Browserstack seesion I'm trying to invoke a GET request from some (external) endpoint, seems like it won't do it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to test an http GET request from Browserstack, or are you trying invoke a GET request from somewhere that hits a Browserstack session? Can you provide some example code for where you at this point?

Comment: I'm executing some session in Browserstack, during which I'm trying to invoke a GET request from some third party end point. The GET request doesn't happen within Browserstack's browser itself (not from its address line), but from my Python code, during Browserstack's session.